# Where to exclude retweets in this tweepy script?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the following code which allows me to view a stream of 1% of the twitter firehose via python:

```
import sys
import tweepy

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = "" 


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if '' in status.text.lower():
            print status.text
            print status.coordinates

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['example'])
```

I know the syntax `include_rts = False` will remove retweets from the stream I am viewing, but I am not sure where to add it to the above code.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the following condition to the on_status function in your listener:

```
def on_status(self, status):
    if '' in status.text.lower() and 'retweeted_status' not in status:
        print status.text
        print status.coordinates
```