# Exclude retweets using tweepy's API.search function

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using the `tweepy` library in `python` to search for tweets that contain a certain word. Retrieving all tweets results in a long list, which also includes a lot of retweets. I want to exclude these retweets. The following code works, but now each tweet is processed (also the retweets), which is not ideal considering the rate limit:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
query = 'test'
max_tweets = 100
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets):
    jsontweet = json.dumps(tweet._json)
    jsontweet = json.loads(jsontweet)
    if not 'retweeted_status' in jsontweet:
        print(tweet)
```

Is there a way in which I can specify within my search request to not include retweets? I found that I could include `include_rts = False` in my code [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608059/where-to-exclude-retweets-in-this-tweepy-script), but I do not know where, and whether it is also working for the `API.search` function. I was unable to find how to include this parameter in this function in the [tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#help-methods).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689566/exclude-retweets-from-twitter-streaming-api-using-tweepy  looks like this has already been answered

Comment: The answer to that question results in the same problem: Tweets need to be processed first, before it can be determined whether or not it is a retweet...